# Gradle build fails because of Nexus returning 400 Bad Request

Tags: gradle, nexus

We have a company-wide Nexus 3 server which

- hosts our own artifacts and
- is used as proxy to Maven Central and other repos.

The developers use two repositories:

- maven-releases for all released/stable artifacts with the [version policy](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/maven.html#maven-repository-format) "Release" and
- maven-snapshots for all snapshots artifacts with the version policy "Snapshot".

Both repositories are used in a Gradle build:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        name "snapshots"
        url "http://nexus3.server:8081/repository/maven-snapshots"
    }

    maven {
        name "releases"
        url "http://nexus3.server:8081/repository/maven-releases"
    }
}
```

Now when Gradle tries to resolve a snapshot-dependency it asks the releases-repository, Nexus answers with

```
Error 400 Bad Request
Repository version policy: RELEASE does not allow version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

and the build fails with

```
> Could not resolve group.id:artifact-id:1.0-SNAPSHOT.
 Required by:
     :my-project:unspecified
  > Could not resolve group.id:artifact-id:1.0-SNAPSHOT.
     > Could not get resource 'http://nexus3.server:8081/repository/maven-releases/group/id/artifact-id/1.0-SNAPSHOT/artifact-id-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'http://nexus3.server:8081/repository/maven-releases/group/id/artifact-id/1.0-SNAPSHOT/artifact-id-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
```

How do I need to configure Gradle so that this error is ignored and the next repository ("snapshots") is tried? Or is it possible to configure Nexus to return 404 Not Found instead of 400 Bad Request?

Version: Gradle 2.9

Comment: Gradle checks repos in the order in which they are declared. Which repo is your snapshot dependency in? From the error message it would seem gradle already tried the snapshots repo, didn't find the dependency, tried the releases one and then failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RaGe's comment was a good hint: The dependency was neither in `snapshots` nor in `releases` but in a third repository which I was not aware of. After adding the third repository to Gradle the dependency was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Nexus Repository Manager 3 documentation for [gradle usage](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/maven.html#gradle) as well as the [example projects](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/tree/nexus-3.x/gradle). That should show you how to use a init.gradle for downloading from the repository group.

Answer (score 0):

One other issue I found while uploading a build:

Make sure you don't have `-SNAPSHOT` on your version name while uploading to Staging!

`-SNAPSHOT` versions are not accepted.